# How to modify the default receiver list in system Mail app

Tags: objective-c, email

I'm using Objective-C. I wonder is there any plug-ins or libraries that can allow me to modify the default receiver list in system Mail app?

For example, I have made an app which can scan a card and fetch the E-mail information on it.

Now, I'd like to put the E-mail data I've fetched into system Mail app's receiver list. That is, when I use the system Mail app and write a new mail, I can see the E-mail address I fetched when I type some letters in the receiver column.

Is that possible to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This list is stored as a Sqlite database and it should be possible to append to it from another process, even while Mail.app is running. I haven't tested it, though.

The following article should help. It describes how to delete entries but adding new ones would work in pretty much the same way: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20110516152604993

Comment: Well, I've worked it out before I see your reply, I goes in the similar way as you have mentioned. I just use sqlite3 to modify the system database, and it works. Thanks anyway!